# How to print stacktrace once an exception is thrown before the catch block (stack unwinding)

Tags: c++11, exception, stack-trace, stack-unwinding

Let's say we have the following code:

```
#include <exception>


void funcA() {
    funcB();
}

void funcB() {
    funcC();
}

void funcC() {
    funcD();
}

void funcD() {
    throw std::runtime_error("Exception!!"); //3
}

void funcE() {
    int * p;
    delete p; //4
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    try {
        funcA(); //1
    } catch (std::exception exc) {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << endl; //2
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want to print the stack trace with the line number of the thrown exception in a multi-threaded efficient way.

I've been checking the last couple of days the solutions and approaches people are doing but unfortunately nothing was useful in my case. I can use for example the boost library `boost::stacktrace::stacktrace()` in `//2` or any other library but the problem here is I have to catch the exception to do this and this approach is not efficient if your code has hundreds of nested functions. You can't just go over all of them and wrap each one with `try-catch` and handle them separately.

So basically what I need to do is if an exception is thrown at `//3` I should be able to print the stack trace of the exception in `//2

I'm aware of the stack unwinding and how it works, but as far as I understand whenever your code reaches the catch block this means that the exception stack has been unwinded and you can't get it. **Please correct me if I'm wrong!**

Is there a way at least to add something similar to middleware before unwinding the exception stack? Or do I have to do it manually?

##### Edit:

Also, what would happen when I can `funcE()` is a memory access exception but this exception is never caught. Is there a way to catch such kind of exceptions or at least print its stack trace before the crash?

##### Note:

I'm running my code on Linux and macOS, C++11 with Silicon web framework.
It's a big system so I'm trying to achieve some logging mechanism that can be used across the system.

Comment: Instead of throwing a generic exception like `runtime_error`, perhaps add your own class hierarchy of more semantically significant exceptions which can help narrow down the possible places where each exception could be thrown. Then add some significant description for each exception so each text is unique and can be used to locate the exact place the exception was thrown.

Comment: Another possible way (which could be combined with the above) is to use a special function or perhaps even a preprocessor macro to throw the exceptions, and this function or macro could add such information such as backtrace or source location, either to a log or as part of the exception itself.

Comment: I added the `runtime_error` as an example, the code might throw any kind of exceptions and I won't be able to add `try-catch` blocks to all of the functions in the system even though I had a custom exception classes @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Is there any example or concept I can search for regarding the macros thing? @Someprogrammerdude 
Thanks in advance dude :)

Comment: You should not add `try catch` everywhere, only at certain points high up where it makes sense and the exceptions can actually be handled. Also note that some exceptions might not be able to handle, and you should let them continue up for program termination. Also remember that exceptions should be reserved for truly exceptional problems. If you have an error that can be recovered from (like failure to open an *optional* file) then there's usually no need to throw an exception for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this in case anyone came across the same question and wanted a quick useful answer.

I've ended up overriding the main C++ throw exception behavior using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nkuln/2020860)

I've changed a few things in the `__cxa_throw` function to tackle my own issue and used `boost::stacktrace` to get a more human-readable stack trace.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

typedef void (*cxa_throw_type)(void *, void *, void (*) (void *));
cxa_throw_type orig_cxa_throw = 0;

void load_orig_throw_code()
{
    orig_cxa_throw = (cxa_throw_type) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "__cxa_throw");
}

extern "C"
void __cxa_throw (void *thrown_exception, void *pvtinfo, void (*dest)(void *)) {
    printf(" ################ DETECT A THROWN !!!!! #############\n");
    if (orig_cxa_throw == 0)
        load_orig_throw_code();
    
    {
        static int throw_count = 0;
        void *array[10];
        size_t size;

        size = backtrace(array, 10);
        fprintf(stderr, "#### EXCEPTION THROWN (#%d) ####\n", ++throw_count);
        backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, 2); // 2 == stderr
    }
    
    orig_cxa_throw(thrown_exception, pvtinfo, dest);
}
```